# Как вывести ежедневные записи в течении 30 дней

Tags: php, mysql, sql, циклы

Делают график посещений сайта, все заходы на сайт вносятся в таблицу MySQL. К примеру мне нужен график за последние 30 дней, соответственно надо 30 точек которые  содержат сумму заходов за сутки, если выполнить запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(userhash) 
  FROM stats 
 WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

в таком случае выведется одно общее число за 30 дней. Как вывести `COUNT` за каждый день в течении этих 30 дней? Пытался сделать через цикл в PHP, но тоже не получается. Буду благодарен за ваши советы

Comment: добавить `group by date(date)`

Comment: @Mike, красавчик, добавь как ответ, закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря Mike, решил вопрос вот так:

```
 SELECT COUNT(userhash) FROM stats WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY GROUP BY date(date)
```